# Killing and reviving TV Characters

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

This program displays a list of TV characters. You can kill them off by random or bring them back by name. I have used the `random.choice` function. I've defined a couple of functions so that the `while loop` looks a little more clean. In two of the functions, `bring_back` and `check_decision`, we assign True to `invalid_input` if user input is invalid, like a flag.
This program is for learning purposes.

```
from random import choice

tv_characters = [
    'john', 'henry', 'maria', 'jason', 
    'max', 'lara', 'gilbert', 'paris'
    ]

killed_tv_characters = []
valid_decision_input = ['kill off', 'bring back']

start_prompt = "Would you like to start (yes/no)?"
decision_prompt = "\nWould you like to bring back a character you killed?"
decision_prompt += "\nOr would you like to kill off another character?"
decision_prompt += "\nEnter 'kill off' or 'bring back' ->"
character_from_dead_prompt = "\nPlease enter the name of character you would like to bring back: "
confirm_kill_prompt = "\nEnter 'kill off' to kill your first character: "




def kill_tv_characters():
    """Kills a random tv character and displays the name on the screen."""
    if tv_characters:
        killed_tv_character = choice(tv_characters)
        tv_characters.remove(killed_tv_character)
        print(f"You have killed off {killed_tv_character.title()}")
        killed_tv_characters.append(killed_tv_character)
    else:
        print("You have killed off all the characters!")

def bring_back(name):
    """Brings back a dead character."""
    name = name.lower().strip()
    if name in killed_tv_characters:
        killed_tv_characters.remove(name)
        tv_characters.append(name)
        print(f"\nYou have brought {name.title()} back to life!")
    elif name in tv_characters:
        print(f"{name} isn't dead!")
        invalid_input = True
    else:
        print(f"{name} isn't a character!")
        invalid_input = True

def check_decision(user_input):
    """Checks user input for decision."""
    if user_input in valid_decision_input and user_input == 'kill off':
        return user_input
    elif user_input in valid_decision_input and user_input == 'bring back':
        return user_input
    else:
        invalid_input == True
        print("Please enter a valid input!")
print("\nYou can kill off characters randomly and add them back my name!")


start = input(start_prompt)
if start == 'yes':
    start = True
else:
    start = False


while tv_characters and start:
    invalid_input = None

    print("\nThese are the living TV characters:")
    for tv_character in tv_characters:
        print(tv_character.title()) 
    if killed_tv_characters:
        user_decision = input(decision_prompt)
        decision = check_decision(user_decision)
        if invalid_input:
            continue
        if decision == 'kill off':
            kill_tv_characters()
        if decision == 'bring back':
            character_from_dead = input(character_from_dead_prompt)
            bring_back(character_from_dead)
            if invalid_input:
                continue

    else:
        confirm_kill = input(confirm_kill_prompt)
        if confirm_kill != 'kill off':
            print("You have entered an invalid input.")
            continue
        kill_tv_characters()

            
if tv_characters == False:
    print("You have killed off all the characters.")
    print("Thanks for playing!")

else:
    print("Goodbye")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### User interface decisions

Having a `start` option is an odd choice. If the user started the program itself, is it likely that they don't want to start the rest of its logic?

### Successive concatenation

This:

```
decision_prompt = "\nWould you like to bring back a character you killed?"
decision_prompt += "\nOr would you like to kill off another character?"
decision_prompt += "\nEnter 'kill off' or 'bring back' ->"
```

is better off as

```
DECISION_PROMPT = '''
Would you like to bring back a character you killed?
Or would you like to kill off another character?
Enter 'kill off' or 'bring back' ->'''
```

### Data structures

It seems that the order of `killed_tv_characters` does not matter, so it should be a `set`, not a `list`.

### Input validation

This:

```
"""Checks user input for decision."""
if user_input in valid_decision_input and user_input == 'kill off':
    return user_input
elif user_input in valid_decision_input and user_input == 'bring back':
    return user_input
else:
    invalid_input == True
    print("Please enter a valid input!")
```

has a few problems:

- `invalid_input == True` doesn't do what you think it does; it's a no-effect statement
- This doesn't really benefit from the combination of `valid_decision_input` (which should be a `set`) and checking for specific strings
- Early-return means that you don't need to use `else`

Here is an alternative:

```
if user_input in valid_decision_input:
    return user_input
invalid_input = True
print("Please enter a valid input!")
```

Other concerns:

- This will set a local `invalid_input` unless you declare it `global` at the top
- Rather than returning a string, consider returning an `Enum` to narrowly represent user choice

### Booleans

This:

```
if tv_characters == False:
```

should be

```
if not tv_characters:
```

Comment: Why do I need a set, doesn’t a list do the job too?

Comment: _do the job_ is a little loaded. Certainly a list will work, but a set will be more efficient for your application in this case.

Comment: The "why" is because `valid_decision_input` is being used for membership tests, which have better time complexity in sets than in sequences.